# Failed to run dexer titanium

Tags: titanium

```
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\titanium_prep.win32.exe "com.voxcinemas.voxcinemasdev" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\assets" "app.js" "config.js" "gcm.js" "gcm_activity.js" "icons.js" "iphone/lib/db.js" "iphone/lib/genericWindow.js" "iphone/lib/helper.js" "iphone/lib/httpClient.js" "iphone/lib/indicator.js" "iphone/lib/style.js" "iphone/lib/styleIOS7.js" "iphone/lib/views.js" "iphone/lib/viewsIOS7.js" "iphone/lib/youtube.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/applicationTabGroup.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/buyTicketsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/cardDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/cinemasWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/detailPageWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/error.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/expDetailWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/expWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/favCinemasDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/favCinemasWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/moviesWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/myAccountWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/offerWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/offerWindowStep2.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/paymentWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/rewardsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/termsConditionsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/ticketConfirmationWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/todayWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/transactionHistoryWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/userDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontroller/webView.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/applicationTabGroup.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/buyTicketsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/cardDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/cinemasWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/detailPageWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/error.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/expDetailWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/expWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/favCinemasDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/favCinemasWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/moviesWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/myAccountWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/offerWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/offerWindowStep2.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/paymentWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/rewardsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/termsConditionsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/ticketConfirmationWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/todayWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/transactionHistoryWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/userDetailsWindow.js" "iphone/viewcontrollerIOS7/webView.js" "lib/db.js" "lib/genericWindow.js" "lib/helper.js" "lib/httpClient.js" "lib/indicator.js" "lib/style.js" "lib/views.js" "lib/youtube.js" "viewcontroller/androidHomeWindow.js" "viewcontroller/buyTicketsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/cardDetailsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/detailPageWindow.js" "viewcontroller/error.js" "viewcontroller/expDetailWindow.js" "viewcontroller/favCinemasDetailsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/favCinemasWindow.js" "viewcontroller/myAccountWindow.js" "viewcontroller/offerWindow.js" "viewcontroller/offerWindowStep2.js" "viewcontroller/paymentWindow.js" "viewcontroller/rewardsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/termsConditionsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/ticketConfirmationWindow.js" "viewcontroller/transactionHistoryWindow.js" "viewcontroller/userDetailsWindow.js" "viewcontroller/webView.js" "ti.cloud.js" "_app_props_.json"
[INFO] :   Writing E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\assets\app.json
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.res.zip
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[INFO] :   Generating E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\res\values\theme.xml
[INFO] :   Packaging application: C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\gen" "-M" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\assets" "-S" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\res" "-I" "C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar" "-F" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.android.gms" "-S" "C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Temp\115824-4792-1rzrtiq/res" "-S" "C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Temp\115824-4792-ljesl8/res"
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx256M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\net.iamyellow.gcmjs\0.1\gcmjs.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\net.iamyellow.gcmjs\0.1\lib\gcm.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\map.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\lib\google-play-services-base.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\lib\google-play-services-map.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\com.onecowstanding.flurry\1.1.1\flurry.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\com.onecowstanding.flurry\1.1.1\lib\FlurryAgent.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\analytics.google\3.1.0\analytics.google.jar;E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\analytics.google\3.1.0\lib\google-play-services.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\kroll-apt.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;Manifest.class;R.class;AssetCryptImpl.class;VoxCinemasActivity.class;VoxCinemasAppInfo.class;VoxCinemasApplication.class" "-d" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\java-sources.txt"
[INFO] :   Running dexer: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe "-Xmx256M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools" "-jar" "C:\Users\Ramesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\lib\dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\classes.dex" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\build\android\bin\classes" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\net.iamyellow.gcmjs\0.1\gcmjs.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\net.iamyellow.gcmjs\0.1\lib\gcm.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\map.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\lib\google-play-services-base.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\ti.map\2.3.3\lib\google-play-services-map.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\com.onecowstanding.flurry\1.1.1\flurry.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\com.onecowstanding.flurry\1.1.1\lib\FlurryAgent.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\analytics.google\3.1.0\analytics.google.jar" "E:\Titanium\voxcinemastitanium\modules\android\analytics.google\3.1.0\lib\google-play-services.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\kroll-common.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\titanium.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar" "C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.0.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar"
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail. What do you want to acheive? What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah we'll need a little more than that...

Comment: Hey  I am new in titanium .if possible come teamview

Answer (score 0):

Searching google leads to:

run

`ti config android.dx.maxMemory 512M`

[source](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/177319/random-error-failed-to-run-dexer)

perhaps that helps in your case, too. Otherwise please more information (code, platform, system specs). `ti info` helps